# accessing json data in python and fast api

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary, fastapi

```
test_data = {
        "transactions": [{
                "id": 5494,
                "specific_wallet_id": 2079,
                "evaluation_process_transaction_id": 5229,
                "transaction_type": "Earn",
                "points": 9,
                "created_at": "2022-09-20T16:14:19.000+05:30",
                "updated_at": "2022-09-20T16:14:19.000+05:30",
                "custom_wallet_transaction_id": "null",
                "order_meta_data": {},
                "points_validity": "2023-09-20T00:00:00.000+05:30",
                "points_status": "Active",
                "transaction_amount": 450.0,
                "transaction_at": "2022-09-20T16:14:18.000+05:30",
                "tnx_status": "Successful",
                "current_points": 9,
                "programme_id": 4,
                "customer_id": 1,
                "reason_code": "Earn",
                "channel": "app",
                "order_id": "1",
                "transaction_references": "null",
                "points_value": 9.0,
                "issuer": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "oo",
                    "code": "oo",
                    "image_url": "null"
                },
                "partner": null
                
            },
            {
                "id": 5486,
                "specific_wallet_id": 2079,
                "evaluation_process_transaction_id": 5221,
                "transaction_type": "Earn",
                "points": 9,
                "created_at": "2022-09-20T15:46:15.000+05:30",
                "updated_at": "2022-09-20T15:46:15.000+05:30",
                "custom_wallet_transaction_id": "null",
                "order_meta_data": {},
                "points_validity": "2023-09-20T00:00:00.000+05:30",
                "points_status": "Active",
                "transaction_amount": 450.0,
                "transaction_at": "2022-09-20T15:46:14.000+05:30",
                "tnx_status": "Successful",
                "current_points": 9,
                "programme_id": 4,
                "customer_id": 2189,
                "reason_code": "Earn",
                "channel": "app",
                "order_id": "uuu",
                "transaction_references": "null",
                "points_value": 9.0,
                "issuer": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "oo",
                    "code": "ooo",
                    "image_url": "null"
                },
                "partner": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "qq",
                    "code": "qq",
                    "image_url": "https://d157777v0iph40..net///offers/avis.jpg"
                }
            }
        ],
        "success": "true",
        "error": "null"
    }

results=[]
results.extend(
    [

        AllTransaction(
            issuer_id=Config.evaluation_issuer_id,
            issuer_name="",
            issuer_logo="",
            wallet_id=o["specific_wallet_id"],
            partner=o["partner"],
            points=o["points"],
            points_value_in_currency=(
                o["points"] * 1
            ),
            transaction_at=o["transaction_at"],
            transaction_id=o["id"],
            transaction_type=o["transaction_type"],
            transaction_meta={
                "order_id": o["order_id"],
                "channel": o["channel"],
                "order_meta_data": o["order_meta_data"],
            },
            transaction_name=o["transaction_type"],
        )
        for o in test_data["transactions"]
    ]
)
return TransactionResponse(results=results)
```

**model code**

```
   class TransactionDetailsPartner(BaseModel):
            partner: Optional[dict] =None
class TransactionDetails(BaseModel):
    points: int
    points_value_in_currency: float
    transaction_id: int
    transaction_at: datetime
    transaction_type: str
    transaction_meta: Optional[dict]
    transaction_name: Optional[TransactionType]
class TransactionDetailsIssuer(BaseModel):
    issuer_id: int
    issuer_name: str
    issuer_logo: str
    wallet_id: int
class AllTransaction(TransactionDetails, TransactionDetailsIssuer, TransactionDetailsPartner):
    pass
```

**this is my main method and here my **partner**data is null in one entry at **test_data**
and in pydantic model i made as optional but still it throwing error if i pass null data how to resolve this                        **

**how to access this partner key even it is null and at model or api level is ok.
thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

The code that you gave is not valid Python, null is a valid JSON value but in Python it has to be None.

Try to load the string as JSON and then parse it to a Pydantic model.

Comment: i understand but i am calling external api here and i need to loop through json for some reason(i need to append some data) while doing so partner object may have or not data it will give null(from response) if partner data is there i am receiving response if it is null  error is coming.

Comment: I understand that the JSON is coming from somewhere, but as long as you provide `null` rather than `None` to a `BaseModel` that has an optional field, it won't work. It would help if you could create a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Comment: its worked     transaction_meta=o["partner] after reading like this